# goroutine not writting to channel

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I'm having a problem with the code below

```
func (h *Handler) GeneratePdfFromHTML(c echo.Context) (err error) {
    req := &createPdfFromHTMLRequest{}
    if err := req.bind(c); err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, utils.NewError(err))
    }

    rawDecodedText, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(req.HTML)
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, utils.NewError(err))
    }

    buf := make(chan []byte)

    go func() {
        defer close(buf)
        pdf, err := pdf.GenerateFromHTML(string(rawDecodedText))
        if err == nil {
            buf <- pdf
        }
    }()

    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, utils.NewError(err))
    }

    return c.Blob(http.StatusOK, MIMEApplicationPdf, <-buf)
}
```

Inside the goroutine `pdf` receives from `GenerateFromHTML` but `buf` doesn't receive any value and so the function this code is inside returns a byte with size 0.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are writing to the channel if there is an error, at which point pdf is likely to be empty. Write when there is no error.

Comment: Are you sure, err != nil? Check it first, and log/panic if it `pdf.GenerateFromHTML` returns error. Also, post full code. In your example, code may exit before anything posted to channel.

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski you're absolutely right about `err != nil`. Maybe I should stop using font ligature in my code. I'll post the full code so you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is synchronous by its nature. Handler produces a slice of bytes and should return that slice using [c.Blob](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/response/#send-blob) method when *these bytes are ready*.

Posted code starts work in goroutine, *does not wait for that work completion* and returns empty bytes slice.

You can fix that by removing goroutine:

```golang
data, err := pdf.GenerateFromHTML(string(rawDecodedText))
if err == nil {
    // handle error here
}
return c.Blob(http.StatusOK, MIMEApplicationPdf, data)
```

The only issue with this code is loading all data in memory, but it is unavoidable if `pdf.GenerateFromHTML` returns `[]byte`.
You can improve that if necessary by updating `pdf.GenerateFromHTML` to return `io.Reader` and use [c.Stream](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/response/#send-stream).

Comment: It's a great idea to use stream, I'll have a look in implementing this code like that. Thanks a lot